# Non self-intersecting representatives in fundamental class

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups, curves

If $X$ is a Riemann surface with boundary $\partial X$ and $\pi_1(X,p)$ is its fundamental group, $p \in X$, then we shall call class $[\gamma] \in \pi_1(X,p)$ primitive (or generator) if it can not be represented as a power of another class. It is stated that every primitive class has a non self-intersecting representative $\gamma$. But how to show this? I also think that every nonprimitive class doesn't have any non self-intersecting representative (intuitively), but is it true?

UPD. A 2-plane with 2 holes may be a counterexample. I should reformulate the question: is it always possible to choose generators of $\pi_1(X,p)$ in such a manner that the property from the question holds?

Answer (score 1):

Non self-intersecting generators of $\pi_1(X)$ are easy enough to give. For boundaryless surfaces, if you puncture the surface and consider a deformation retract on to a finite wedge of circles, each of the embedded circles will generate $\pi_1(X)$. Now, if we then start cutting out disks, the boundary components will also contribute to the generators and should be included. This collection of boundary circles, and embedded wedge of circles are generating loops of the entire fundamental group by the classification of surfaces with boundary.

Comment: Oh, the answer is a bit over my level. Why every punctured boundaryless Riemann surface deformation retracts to a finite wedge of circles and why each of the embedded circles will generate $\pi_1(X)$? Any reference is very welcome

Comment: Oh I'm sorry if I aimed it a little too high. You tagged the question with the algebraic topology tag so I thought the above terms might be well-known to you. I'll try to reword the answer when I have some spare time to include more detail. In the mean time, any introductory book on algebraic topology should give a proof using Van-Kampen's theorem that a generating set of the fundamental group of an orientable surface of genus $g$ is given by $2g$ generators (essentially by puncturing and deformation retracting onto a wedge of circles). The first chapter of...

Comment: ...  [this](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~bgabi/Farb%20Magalit%20January%202011%20version.pdf) book might be a good place to start when thinking about non self-intersecting curves on surfaces.